# How to change Show Applications Icon in dock Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, dock

As the title says, I want to change the "Show Applications" Grid Icon in ubuntu dock (17.10) with Ubuntu Icon like in Unity 8.I have found a similar question but the answer has no result.
Thanks in advance.