# How to change "Show Apps" icon on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome-shell, dock, ubuntu-dock

As the title says, I want to change the "Show Applications" Icon in Ubuntu dock (on Ubuntu 17.10) with Ubuntu icon like in Unity 10.04.

[image]

I have **found a similar question but the answer has no result**.
[How to change Show Applications Icon in dock Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979214/how-to-change-show-applications-icon-in-dock-ubuntu-17-10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Show Applications" icon is usually the `view-app-grid-symbolic.svg` file under your icon theme directory. So you can change the "Show Applications" icon by overriding that file.

For example, in case of Adwaita icon theme, the `view-app-grid-symbolic.svg` file is located at `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/scalable/actions/`. To change it with a custom icon of your choice (say `my-icon.svg`), just copy `my-icon.svg` to the aforementioned directory and rename it as `view-app-grid-symbolic.svg`. You may run the following command to do that

```
sudo cp /path/to/my-icon.svg /usr/share/icons/Adwaita/scalable/actions/view-app-grid-symbolic.svg
```

Note a couple of things:

1. Be very careful while making changes inside the root directory. It's always better to take a backup of the file before replacing it. In case anything goes wrong you'll be able to revert the change.
2. The change you'll make most probably be overwritten once an associated package gets updated. So you'll have to make the change again.

For other icon themes the correct location of the `view-app-grid-symbolic.svg` file may be `/usr/share/icons/ICON_THEME_DIRECTORY/actions/symbolic` or `/usr/share/icons/ICON_THEME_DIRECTORY/symbolic/actions`. Or if the icon theme directory is located inside your home directory, try `~/.icons/ICON_THEME_DIRECTORY/...` or `~/.local/share/icons/ICON_THEME_DIRECTORY/...` etc.

Comment: thanks, but i dont have svg icon, can i rename a png file to svg and use it, or where can i find svg icons?

Comment: @CloudSky You can rename and use. Also log out and log in again after making the change.

Comment: @CloudSky Note that *symbolic* .svg images behave substantially different from .png. While the first one adapts to the current theme color, the second does not. Also note that replacing the file might effect other applications or places where the icon is used.